# Accessing a property in child class with message style syntax

Tags: objective-c

I am completely new to objective-c and I am currently in the learning process, 
I have a parent class A which a property a, 
I am trying to access the property in a subclass B, 
When I access the property and assign a value like this

```
[self a:3];
```

it does complain No visible @interface for B declares selector a

but if I access it to read from it like
    int something = [self a];
then it does not complain.

I understand the recommended way to access properties is using the . between object and property, but technically speaking it should work with message style call. but it's not, so please advise me on this.

my code is like this

```
// Test class A
@interface A : NSObject

@property int a;

-(void) initMe; 

@end

@implementation A

@synthesize a;

-(void) initMe
{
 NSLog(@"I am in A");
}
@end

//-------------------------

@interface B : A

-(void) initEx; 

@end

@implementation B

-(void) initEx
{
    // This line gives a problem as I mentioned above
    [self a:3];
    NSLog(@"In child class B");
}

@end

///-----------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[self a:3];` is the wrong syntax. If you want to call the setter method, it should be:

```
[self setA:3];
```

Comment: Thanks but its strange when I want to read a value [self a] works rather than [self getA]. Why this different naming style for getting and setting .. :(

Comment: @Ahmed You can find all about it here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW17

Comment: Because that's the Apple convention. Never use `get...`, always use `set...`.